# Retrieving block hash of current block vs previous block

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, remix

What is the formula for retrieving the blockhash of 1) previous block and of 2) current block?

Comment: You cannot get the block hash of the current block from inside the EVM.

Comment: is that because it doesn't know the current block till it has been settled which means that it will be a past block anyway?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the previous block's hash by using `blockhash(block.number - 1)`. However, as mentioned in the comments, you cannot obtain the current block's header within that transaction because the transaction that is running has not been included in the block yet.