# Why blockhash returns zero always?

Tags: hash

I have a problem with understanding. I created a utility function, safeMath() , which I run first to create the block. Next, I get the block number, which is usually in the range from 10 to 14. And then I try to get the hash of this block, but I get zeros.

In the code below, the blockh variable always return 0x000...

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";

contract getBlockhash {
    uint a = 5;
    uint b = 2;
    uint public c;
    bytes32 public blockh;
    uint public blockn;

    using SafeMath for uint256;

    function hashBlock() public {
        blockn = block.number;      
        blockh = blockhash(blockn);
    }

    function safeMath() public {
        c = a.sub(b);
    }

}
```

Comment: Remember that it's normal for blockhash to return 0x00 for the current block. See https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/69514/retrieving-block-hash-of-current-block-vs-previous-block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Remix?

Because this seems to be a remix issue.

I used your code and modified it a bit so I can play experiment with it. And it does return awkward results. (I only get real Blockhash for block.number = 0 )

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";

contract Blockhash {
    uint a = 5;
    uint b = 2;
    uint public c;
    bytes32 public blockh;
    uint public blockn;

    using SafeMath for uint256;

    function getBlockNumber() public view returns(uint) {
        return block.number;
    }

    function getBlockhash(uint blocknumber) public view returns(bytes32) {
        return blockhash(blocknumber);
    }

    function hashBlock() public {
        blockn = block.number;
        blockh = blockhash(blockn);
    }

    function safeMath() public {
        c = a.sub(b);
    }

}
```

Comment: don't worry it will give real hash in real blockchain. and for tests, you can put 32 random bytes

Comment: So it's really just a Remix issue?

Comment: I don't use Remix, so can't tell. But if you want to try your contract upload it to test net or create local chain using `geth` and you will see the hash properly set